# leaflet editable restrict draw to a specific area

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

In [Leaflet.Editable](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable) I want to confine/limit my customers to draw only in a specific area/bounds.

actually im trying to limit them to (90, -90, 180, -180) bounds of map..

```
maxBounds: [[-90, -180], [90, 180]]
```

[image]
[image]
I was not able to find anything anywhere and it seems that i am missing something.

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/mikila85/pen/rjqmLe)

please help.

---

EDIT:

the Y axis is blocking correctly and mouse cannot stretch shape beyond top and bottom.

the problem is in X axis (as seen in pictures)

as for now i solved it with after save check and clear shape if it out of map bounds (BAD USER EXPERIENCE). i need a mouse confinement just like y axis does.

Comment: Can you set [max bounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds) on the map itself?

Comment: i did and it does not limit the shape from going outside the bounds.

Comment: I was able to come up with some code that prevents drawing and moving polylines and polygons out of bounds, maybe someone can extend and improve on that: https://plnkr.co/edit/w64aeCXGMt7odCmM79E7?p=preview Does not work properly with rectangles and circles, markers can still be dragged out as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your use case (why the whole world map??) Quickest and easiest fix would be to simply set the map's `minZoom` to something a bit higher, for example, I found that `minZoom: 5` was adequate except for cases where the map was both really short and really wide (which is rarely the case in most apps I've seen).

But the real fix involves writing your own custom overrides for dragging markers and shapes.

[According to API doc](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.Editable/doc/api.html) the L.Editable plugin allows you to override a bunch of stuff including the `VertexMarker` class, via `map.editTools.options.vertexMarkerClass`.

Fixed codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrPpRY?editors=0010

This snippet of code that allows you to constrain the longitude for dragging vertex markers by correcting values under -180 and over 180 is this:

```
// create custom vertex marker editor
var vertexMarkerClass = L.Editable.VertexMarker.extend({
  onDrag: function(e) {
    e.vertex = this;
    var iconPos = L.DomUtil.getPosition(this._icon),
      latlng = this._map.layerPointToLatLng(iconPos);

    // fix out of range vertex
    if (latlng.lng < -180) {
      e.latlng.lng = latlng.lng = -180;
      this.setLatLng(latlng);
    }
    if (latlng.lng > 180) {
      e.latlng.lng = latlng.lng = 180;
      this.setLatLng(latlng);
    }

    this.editor.onVertexMarkerDrag(e);

    this.latlng.update(latlng);
    this._latlng = this.latlng; // Push back to Leaflet our reference.
    this.editor.refresh();
    if (this.middleMarker) this.middleMarker.updateLatLng();
    var next = this.getNext();
    if (next && next.middleMarker) next.middleMarker.updateLatLng();
  }
});

// attach custom editor
map.editTools.options.vertexMarkerClass = vertexMarkerClass;
```

I didn't code for dragging the shape as a whole (the rectangle, in this case). While the `VertexMarker` fix should address all kinds of vertex dragging, you need to override each shape's `drag` handler to properly constrain the bounds. And if bounds are exceeded, crop the shape appropriately. As was pointed out, Leaflet already does this for latitude, but because Leaflet allows wrapping the map around horizontally you have your essential problem. Using `rec.on("drag")` to correct the bounds when they cross over your min/max longitude is the only way to address it. It is basically the same solution as I have laid out for the `vertexMarkerClass` - actual code left as exercise for the diligent reader.

Comment: chrki seems to have figured out the part about moving the shapes as a whole. If you combine that solution with my solution for dragging vertex markers you should get what you are looking for

Comment: yup it seems to solve the problem (dragging was never part of my project its in the demo by mistake) .. i just need to figure out how to do this for polygons but i bet it should be just the same. i'll try to follow up. thx :)

Comment: http://codepen.io/mikila85/pen/dNwpxM?editors=0010
if you have a moment to look at this: on add it doesnt work just on edit (look at the button for add shape on the left)

Comment: The plugin author was nice about letting classes be overridden..  I recommend looking at the plugin's source .js file because you can copy and modify / override the methods for adding points as well, look for `L.Editable.PathEditor = L.Editable.BaseEditor.extend` you probably need to also do fix for methods like `addVertexMarker` but really the plugin should probably fix this issue, you might want to reach out to the actual author on github and report as bug or feature request - i don't mind offering a little help, but plugin needs extensive fixes to cover all cases